# loops are not storing the values in my array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm taking input in an array.  But the loops are taking values more than the condition and not storing those values in array. I'm stuck here.

When I'm taking input on x[] array, it takes 1 more input than the condition.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    printf("How much number you have?  : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    float x[n];
    float FofX[n][n];
    float x_variable;

    i=0;

    printf("Enter values of x \n\n");
    while(i!=n){
        printf("When n is %d and i is x[%d]:  ",n,i);
        scanf("%f ",&x[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    i=0;
    while(i!=n){
        printf("x[%d]= %d \n",i,x[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i=0;
    printf("Enter values of f(x) \n");
    while(i!=n){
        printf("When n is %d and i is [%d]:  ",n,i);
        scanf("%f",&FofX[i][0]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nInput value of a variable point\n");
    scanf("%d",&x_variable);
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you practice your debugging skills. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to get started.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to learn about `for` loops. All of your loops could be e.g. `for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: Also read up about `for` loops

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - You beat me by 12 seconds

Comment: As for your problem, please edit your question to show your input, and the actual and expected output.

Comment: Also check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: See [Trailing blank in `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/) for a discussion of why trailing blanks are horrendous UI if a human might be entering the data from a terminal, and not really necessary even if the input will always come from file.